# Beginner question how is this Reactjs destructing pattern better then earlier ways?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, destructuring

I have this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (this.props.width !== newProps.width) {
        setTimeout(this._onResize, 0);
    }
}
```

And eslint warning saying I can change it to this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ width }) {
    const { width2 } = this.props;
    if (width2 !== width) {
        setTimeout(this._onResize, 0);
    }
}
```

The warning went away but is this correct way to do it since It's more code??

Comment: does props contain `width2`? if not, then `width2` will always be undefined (the two code fragments are not equivalent)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks your right Hmm. Think I must change variable names higher up maybe

Comment: maybe you meant `const { width: width2 } = this.props;`

Comment: destructuring is just an easier way to assign values that come from the same object, I would say it's probably rather taste, code guidelines and readability. Destructuring arguments also clearly indicate to any consumer which properties are actually going to be used from a consumer perspective

Comment: @Icepickle your right thanks I did not think of that instead of sending in the hole props

Comment: Icepickle is correct, plus if you are going to refer to the variable multiple times, then the second way is a lot shorter (to not have to type it each time). As such many consider it a better practice to pull all the properties out of `this.props` that you will use at the start of the function, and eslint suggests it. But it is not hard and fast, and eslint is designed to be configurable to match your preferences.

Comment: less code doesn't necessarily mean better.